# This is not a banana

Tags: rebus

A banana has nothing to do with this easy rebus puzzle (and I made it myself); repeat, this is not a banana.

[image: Not a Banana]

Comment: Nice one! Weird title though?

Comment: http://i206.photobucket.com/albums/bb30/papa_soop/bluebanana.jpg

Comment: That is indeed a blue banana you linked to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> Once in a blue moon

Because the picture is literally:

> Ones in a blue moon

And that sounds like the more common phrase

Comment: awwww, you posted the answer even before I submitted the puzzle!

Comment: @BGM The official timestamps record that I answered 36 seconds after it was posted. I just got lucky there.

Comment: @BGM GG your puzzle got owned

Comment: I'm going to change my login name.  I think I'm developing a bad reputation.

Comment: Mr. Toast - I wonder if that's the fastest answer on the site?

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell, BGM. We can ask @MarkHenderson if his [column80](http://stackapps.com/q/542) project pulls timestamps as well and, if it does, can it find the shortest time gap between question post and answer post.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a banana. I've never seen a moon with a face.

Comment: @EngineerToast It [seems](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/216360/fastest-answers) I make the record, but only with a self-answer. BaileyM still beats you with a 25-second job though. Of course, Stack Overflow has all the records; check out [this 1-second job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784867/imagej-unable-to-load-plugins/10784868#10784868)!

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks for doing the legwork. I don't think self answers should count as they can be simulposted so I say glory to Bailey M.

Comment: Agreed; I left him a comment on the relevant answer :-)

Comment: Hey, this'll put me at #3 once the data is updated. Hooray for internet victory without meaning?

Answer (score 3):

> Once in a blue moon, because the moon is blue and has 1s "in" it.